# I there a way, to view the exposed Objective-C header to swift

Tags: ios, swift, evernote, bridge

I have problems to understand, why some member functions from an imported (and complicated) set of Objective-C interface are not available in Swift.

I have a Bridging-Header File:

```
#import "EvernoteSDK.h"
```

and I can't use some member functions in my ViewController

```
let userStore = EvernoteUserStore()
userStore.initWithSession(session)
```

initWithSession is not available for the swift code, but why?

The objective-C header shows:

```
@interface EvernoteUserStore : ENAPI
+ (instancetype)userStore;
- (id)initWithSession:(EvernoteSession *)session;
```

If I could view the exposed Objective-C header, I may understand, how the mangling works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift the initializer call is combined with the constructor. In other words, Objective-C's

```
EvernoteUserStore *userStore = [[EvernoteUserStore alloc] initWithSession:session];
```

becomes

```
let userStore = EvernoteUserStore(session:session);
```

The tool recognizes the `initWithSomething:` name of Objective-C, and converts it to

```
init(something something : SomeType)
```

In case of `EvernoteUserStore` the corresponding `init` method looks like this:

```
init(session session: EvernoteSession!)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer solved my problem. Where I can I find the mangling rules? I come from a c# and c++ background and it seems awkward when just a naming convention dictates a tool behavior.

Comment: @ChaosSpeeder I am not that familiar wit Swift myself, but it looks like name mangling is applied in two situations - `initWith...` initializers, and factory `sometypeWith...` class methods (e.g. `arrayWithObject:` of `NSArray`). These two follow long-standing Cocoa conventions, so the tool makes the translation for you to match the new conventions of Swift. Other methods should stay intact.

Comment: There's a long discussion of the mangling rules in the Apple interoperability docs.

Comment: You should also watch the "Integrating Swift with Objective C" and "Swift Interoperability in Depth" [videos from WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/).